# Saving a string in memory in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to MIPS. I'm working on a bigger task to learn the language. The task requires me to take a string from the user. Here is my code:

```
            .data
msg1:   .asciiz "\nInput: "
msg2:   .asciiz "Output:\n"
input_sentence: .space 1001 
word:   .space 51

            .text

read_input:
    # print "input: "
    li $v0, 4           
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall
    #Take the string from user
    j read_string


read_string:
    #Reads the string into input_sentence
    li $v0,8
    la $a0,input_sentence
    li $a1,1001
    syscall
    jr $ra

        .globl main  
main:
    jal read_input
```

The program runs and asks for input. But it terminates with an error after I press enter. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that main has to be above all the other functions that I define.